# Incorrect Private IP EC2 Instance, Terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Deploying an number of instances in AWS using terraform. The code is written to make use of specific private ip ranges. The code iterates through a range to provide the last two digits on an ip.

```
IP_AA_MGMT_Windows = [for i in range(1, var.Number_of_AA_Candidates +1 ) : format("%s%02d", "10.10.8.1", i)]
```

For information the subnet this belongs to has the following CIDR allocation

```
cidr_block = "10.10.8.0/22"
```

This gives an ip range of 10.10.8.0 - 10.10.11.255

The instance is created with no real problems. Expected private ip is allocated in an identical manner as the network interface.

```
resource "aws_instance" "Windows" {
    instance_type               = "t2.large"
    subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.windows.id
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.AA_Eng_Windows[count.index].id]
    key_name                    = aws_key_pair.ENG-DEV.id
    count                       = var.Number_of_AA_Candidates
    private_ip                  = local.IP_AA_WINLAN_Windows[count.index]
    associate_public_ip_address = false
```

An additional network interface is created and attached to the instance.

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "Windows_Access_Interface" {  
    subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.management.id
    private_ip                  = local.IP_AA_MGMT_Windows[count.index]
    security_groups             = [aws_security_group.Windows.id]
    count                       = var.Number_of_AA_Candidates
    attachment {
      instance                  = aws_instance.Windows[count.index].id
      device_index              = 1
    }
```

All deploys correctly according to terraform. Its not until you check the private ip's in AWS or through terraform state show that you realise the network interface resource is created but with an incorrect private ip, not the one provisioned in the code. NOTE. Terraform plan provides output suggesting no problems with ip allocation.

Below is some of the output from the terrafrom show command.

```
# aws_network_interface.Windows_Access_Interface[0]:
    resource "aws_network_interface" "Windows_Access_Interface" {
    interface_type            = "interface"
    private_ip                = "10.10.10.72"
    private_ip_list           = [
        "10.10.10.72",
    ]
    private_ip_list_enabled   = false
    private_ips               = [
        "10.10.10.72",
    ]
```

NOTE Some of the details in the show have intentionally been removed for security.

The question now is, what is causing this?

Comment: Ok, so what is the issue? Also, what is the value for the `Number_of_AA_Candidates`?

Comment: During the test with the output shown it was 2 Candidates. Regardless of how many instances I create the private ip is not what I've set it to.

Comment: Ah, ok, I managed to understand something: the `"%02d"` part adds a zero at the end of the `"10.10.8.1"` string. So you actually want to add the count value to the last octet?

Comment: That's correct. The most we'll ever have is 15 in the counts so more than enough space there to create the ip's we want. Sometimes the ip provided even has a different 3rd octet than expected.

Comment: Ok, so `format` is really not your best bet here. I can try to find a better solution, but treating IPs as strings is generally not a good idea. Also, if that's the VPC CIDR range, you can't actually use any of the first four IP addresses (reserved by AWS) nor the last one (broadcast IP).

Comment: Thats a really good point regarding the reserved ip's, didn't take that into account.

Answer (score 3):

There are some important points to take into account here. One of the first being that there are five reserved addresses in each VPC [1]:

> The first four IP addresses and the last IP address in each subnet CIDR block are not available for your use, and they cannot be assigned to a resource, such as an EC2 instance.

So that means you would have to start counting the addresses that are assignable from `10.10.8.4`. That further means that in the range function, the counting would have to start after 3:

```
IP_AA_MGMT_Windows = [for i in range(4, var.Number_of_AA_Candidates + 1 ) : format("%s%02d", "10.10.8.1", i)]
```

Since IP addresses are not really strings, the `format` function along with the `%02d` will only add `0` and depending on the `Number_of_AA_Candidates` a certain number of decimal numbers at the end of the string. So for example, if `Number_of_AA_Candidates` was equal to `2`, that would yield the following IP addresses:

```
> local.IP_AA_MGMT_Windows
[
  "10.10.8.101",
  "10.10.8.102",
]
```

Note that this is for the original `range` starting from 1. This looks like it is fine, but consider the case where you would add a double-digit number (or even triple-digit number to drive the point home). Additionally, the second part of the `range` is fine unless you set the `Number_of_AA_Candidates` to a value greater than or equal to the maximum number of IP addresses. If you were somehow to miscalculate, the range would go over and the IP addresses that would be created would not be valid IP addresses. To make sure you do not overstep the maximum number of available IPs in the CIDR range, you can calculate that number with:

```
2^10 - 5
```

10 is the number of bits that remains after subnet bits are deducted from the maximum number of bits which is 32. The 5 is the number of IP addresses that cannot be used. This leaves you with 1019 possible host addresses. To make sure that does not happen, you could introduce the ternary operator for the second part of the `range` function:

```
IP_AA_MGMT_Windows = [for i in range(4, (var.Number_of_AA_Candidates > 1019 ? 1019 : var.Number_of_AA_Candidates + 1) ) : format("%s%02d", "10.10.8.1", i)]
```

Now, those are two issues resolved. The third and final issue is the `format` function. To enable the usage of only available IP addresses and avoid using `format`, I suggest trying the `cidrhost` built-in function [2]. The `cidrhost` syntax is:

> cidrhost(prefix, hostnum)

The `hostnum` part represents the wanted host IP address in the CIDR range. So for example, if you were to do:

```
cidrhost("10.10.8.0/22", 1)
```

This would return the first IP address in the range. For `hostnum` equal to 2 it would return 2nd, and so on.

To use this properly, you would have to modify the local variable to look like this:

```
IP_AA_MGMT_Windows = [for i in range(4, (var.Number_of_AA_Candidates > 1019 ? 1019 : var.Number_of_AA_Candidates + 1)) : cidrhost("10.10.8.0/22", i)]
```

This works well with any number up to the maximum number of host IP addresses. Finally, even though we know there are 5 IP addresses we cannot use, `cidrhost` does not know anything about that and always starts counting from the first to the last number in a CIDR range, so the last expression would have to use 1023 addresses, as we don't want to include the broadcast one (the start IP address is covered because we start from 4):

```
IP_AA_MGMT_Windows = [for i in range(4, (var.Number_of_AA_Candidates > 1023 ? 1023 : var.Number_of_AA_Candidates + 1)) : cidrhost("10.10.8.0/22", i)]
```

**EDIT**: After having a discussion in chat we have identified that there is an issue with the argument in the `aws_network_interface` (even though terraform did not complain about it). The argument in the question is `private_ip` while the provider lists that as `private_ips` which is a list of strings [3]. After changing that to:

```
private_ips = [ local.IP_AA_MGMT_Windows[count.index] ]
```

The apply worked as expected.

---

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/configure-subnets.html#subnet-sizing

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/cidrhost

[3] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/network_interface#private_ips

Comment: Really appreciate the time you've taken to provide this solution. Changes will be made to accomodate the advice you've provided.

Comment: Let me know if this works and acceptance of the answer would be much appreciated if it does work.

Comment: For my particular situation I need specific ip's the fact I'm starting at 10.10.8.1** should negate the concern for assigned ip's. The cidrhost function is great for when I just need any ip but these ip's need to be specified. Regardless of whether I use what you've kindly provided or not. The private ip allocated still is incorrect when deployed.

Comment: What is the address now and what IPs do you actually need?

Comment: In your answer you mention having the producing ip's 10.10.8.101, 10.10.8.102. Using the format enabled me to allocate the last two digits in the final octet. When I run a plan it shows the expected ip's to be correct. But when you apply the changes and deploy, AWS rerturns a completley different ip. One which is not what I need. An example from the above is, 10.10.10.72.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I know where the error is. As per the exact addresses starting from 100, you can set the range to start from there and use it with cidrhost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247711/discussion-between-user15695494-and-marko-e).